# How does this work? Finding final voltage of capacitor in a RC circuit step response problem

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, step-response

There is a circuit with a switch which was in position 1 for a long time and is now in position 2. I attached a picture of the given circuit below.

Once in position 2 I need to find the final voltage over the capacitor. My professor said the final voltage is equal to the 160k resistor, I thought that couldn't be true so I built the circuit in multisim to see and of course, it is true.

What I don't get is why the final voltage of the capacitor is equal to the 160k resistor? I know that after a while, a capacitor will behave like an open circuit but I'm not sure how to connect that with this. I don't know what concept allows the capacitor's voltage to equal the 160k resistor's voltage.

[image: given circuit]

[image: professor drawing]

[image: multisim proof]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Well there is no other voltage there could be over a capacitor than the voltage it is connected to. For example, you connect a capacitor to 9V battery, expect 9V on the capacitor when it's charged, regardless of any current limiting series resistance. What exactly is unclear about this circuit? The resistor divider? It might help to describe what voltage you expected and why?

Comment: Well here it is connected to 75V, but it charges to 60V? By what you said shouldn't it go to 75V? I guess I am confused because I don't have an intuitive idea of what the voltage should be, I thought you would have to find it using kirchoff's laws or something, but according to my instructor it is only logical that it is equal to the 160k resistor's voltage. I don't understand that logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You expect the capacitor to charge to 75V but it isn't connected to 75V.

It is connected to 60V that comes out of the 75V supply divided by a simple voltage divider.

You can exchange the 75V supply and the voltage divider with a Thevenin equivalent of it, with 60V and series resistance.